# vLookup error for VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2010, variant, vlookup

I have a form that has a list of items from which it unhides the relevant item-sheet based on the form selection. Due to the length of item name, each item is assigned an ID. The vlookup function is meant to retrieve the relevant ID based on the matching of names in another sheet.

The code is as follows.

The fundName value being passed in is "AX - Arnold Xchange Securities (USD)".
The fundID is located on the 5th column of the array being searched.
The fundID definitely exists

The problem here is that it gives me a runtime error where it cannot get the vLookup property of the function class. Error 1004

```
Private Sub FundLookupImage_Click()

Dim fundName As String
Dim fundSheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("DownloadTable")
MsgBox ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Count

fundName = Me.FundList.Value
fundName = """" & fundName & """"
MsgBox fundName

fundSheetName = CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fundName, ws.Range("A:F"), 5, True))
MsgBox fundSheetName

Unload Me
End Sub
```

I've tested the vLookup method on excel itself and it retrieves the correct ID

Comment: your vlookup looks correct (if you're sure the list is ordered - if not remove the `True`). Are you sure you need to put `fundName` in quotes? Try removing `fundName = """" & fundName & """"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VLookup makes me crazy always when I have to use it, please try this:

```
DIM searchResult AS variant
    searchResult = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    searchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fundName, ws.Range("A:F"), 5, 0)
    fundSheetName = CStr(searchResult)
```

Comment: Hi there! It works with that error resume. Guess I have to isolate it now 1st. THANKS!!!